# Can anyone simplify this logarithmic function?

Tags: logarithms

The function is:
$$X^{\log_a(Y)}$$

Thanks

edit: This is from my book. The answer given is y* log (base a) X.

But i cant solve. + I am from mobile and never used this site before sorry for formatting

Comment: You can use $\log_y x = \frac{\log x}{\log y} = \log x (\log y)^{-1}$ and  $b^{x\cdot y} = (b^x)^y$, but I wouldn't consider the results "simpler".

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that this can be simplified?

Answer (score 2):

$$
x^{\log_a y}=(e^{\ln x})^{\log_a y}=e^{\frac{\ln x \ln y}{\ln a}}
$$
What else? :|

Answer (score 0):

Using $b^x = e^{\ln(b) \cdot y}$ and $\log_b x = \frac{\log x}{\log b}$:

$X^{\log_a Y} = X^{\frac{\ln Y}{\ln a}} = e^{\frac{\ln X \ln Y}{\ln a}}$

which is clearly symmetric with respect to $X$ and $Y$, so you can do the same computation with $X$ and $Y$ swapped to obtain $Y^{\log_a X}$.